# Does `==` for struct check recursively in Julia ? It seems not

Tags: struct, julia

There is a behavior I don't understand when checking for equality in Julia concerning "struct" objects.
The documentation  states : : "*For collections, `==` is generally called recursively on all contents, though other properties (like the shape for arrays) may also be taken into account*". Though it seems for structs it is cast to `===` or something.
Here is a minimal working exemple :

As expected :

```
string1 = String("S")
string2 = String("S")
string1 == string2
```

=> returns true

and :

```
set1 = Set(["S"])
set2 = Set(["S"])
set1 == set2
```

=> returns true

---

BUT ! And that is what I don't understand :

```
struct StringStruct
    f::String
end
stringstruct1 = StringStruct("S")  
stringstruct2 = StringStruct("S")  
stringstruct1 == stringstruct2
```

=> returns true

However :

```
struct SetStruct  
    f::Set{String}  
end
setstruct1 = SetStruct(Set(["S"]))
setstruct2 = SetStruct(Set(["S"]))
setstruct1 == setstruct2
```

=> returns false

---

To me, it looks like `===`is tested on the elements of the struct.

So my question is : what is the real behavior of `==` when tested on structs ? Does it cast `==` or `===` ? In case it casts `==` as the documentation states, what is the point I misunderstand ?

Comment: Additional info: There's an issue to make structs compare recursively like you mention (https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4648). It's not going to be in any Julia 1.X versions though, so it'll be at least Julia 2.0 before the automatic recursive checking becomes part of the language (if it does at all).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `struct`s by default `==` falls back to `===`, so e.g.:

```
setstruct1 == setstruct2
```

is the same as

```
setstruct1 === setstruct2
```

So now we go down to the way how `===` works. And it is defined as:

> Determine whether `x` and `y` are identical, in the sense that no program could distinguish them.

(I am leaving out the rest of the definition, as I believe this fist sentence builds a nice mental model).

Now clearly `stringstruct1` and `stringstruct2` are non-distinguishable. They are immutable and contain strings that are immutable in Julia. In particular they have the same `hash` value (which is not a definitive test, but is a nice mental model here).

```
julia> hash(stringstruct1), hash(stringstruct2)
(0x9e0bef39ad32ce56, 0x9e0bef39ad32ce56)
```

Now `setstrict1` and `setstruct2` are distinguishable. They store different sets, although at the moment of comparison these sets contain the same elements, but they have different memory locations (so in the future they can be different - in short - they are distinguishable). Note that these structs have different hashes in particular:

```
julia> hash(setstruct1), hash(setstruct2)
(0xe7d0f90913646f29, 0x3b31ce0af9245c64)
```

Now notice the following:

```
julia> s = Set(["S"])
Set{String} with 1 element:
  "S"

julia> ss1 = SetStruct(s)
SetStruct(Set(["S"]))

julia> ss2 = SetStruct(s)
SetStruct(Set(["S"]))

julia> ss1 == ss2
true

julia> ss1 === ss2
true

julia> hash(ss1), hash(ss2)
(0x9127f7b72f753361, 0x9127f7b72f753361)
```

This time `ss1` and `ss2` are passing all the tests, as again they are indistinguishable (if you change `ss1` then `ss2` changes in sync as they hold the same `Set`).

Comment: Great ! That's usefull, complete and clear. Thanls !

Answer (score 1):

While Bogumil's answer explains what is happening let me show how to bring the behavior that you are expecting to your code.

Simply add the following lines.

```
abstract type Comparable end
import Base.==
==(a::T, b::T) where T <: Comparable =
    getfield.(Ref(a),fieldnames(T)) == getfield.(Ref(b),fieldnames(T))
```

Now you can make your struct to be comparable as you wish:

```
struct SetStruct <: Comparable 
    f::Set{String}  
end

setstruct1 = SetStruct(Set(["S"]))
setstruct2 = SetStruct(Set(["S"]))
```

Tesing:

```
julia> setstruct1  == setstruct2
true
```

Comment: Great ! That's usefull to easily compare structs. Thanks.