# For Sets (immutable) and Strings (mutable), the behavior of "===" doesn't seem to comply to the documentation in Julia (v1.5 at least)

Tags: julia, immutability, equality, mutable

I think I am missing a point, as in my tests it seems the behavior of "===" doesn't comply to the documentation.

The documentation states *"First the types of x and y are compared. If those are identical, mutable objects are compared by address in memory and immutable objects (such as numbers) are compared by contents at the bit level"*.

I understand from this definition is that :

- for mutable objects, two distincts objects (ie. different memory address) should not be "`===`"
- for immutable objects, when the contents are identical, they should be "`===`"

**However :**

The **Sets** are immutable, but two identical objects by the content are not "`===`"

```
set1 = Set(["S"])
set2 = Set(["S"])
ismutable(set1)
```

Returns `false`

```
set1 === set2
```

Returns `false`, but according to the documentation should return `true`, as `set1` and `set2` are two immutable objects with identical contents. (or `ismutable(set1)` should return `true`?)

The **Strings** are mutable, but two distinct objects are "`===`"

```
string1 = String("test")
string2 = String("test")
ismutable(string1)
```

Returns `true`

```
string1 === string2
```

Returns `true`, but according to the documentation should return `false` as `string1` and `string2` are two distinct mutable objects, and hence their address in memory should be different. (or `ismutable(string1)` should return `false`?)

---

What is the point I am missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These cases are tricky and I agree that not intuitive. `Set` is a bit easier to explain.

`Set` is defined as:

```
struct Set{T} <: AbstractSet{T}
    dict::Dict{T,Nothing}

    Set{T}() where {T} = new(Dict{T,Nothing}())
    Set{T}(s::Set{T}) where {T} = new(Dict{T,Nothing}(s.dict))
end
```

so you can see that although it is an immutable `struct` its field is a mutable object `dict`. So the comparison of `dict` field uses memory address and all is consistent.

But I agree that it is confusing that `Set` is immutable, but `Dict` is mutable; however, all is consistent here.

---

With `String` the situation is more complex. They are defined to be immutable, see [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/#man-strings):

> As in Java, strings are immutable: the value of an `AbstractString` object cannot be changed. To construct a different string value, you construct a new string from parts of other strings.

but they are implemented in non standard way in Julia Base for performance.

Therefore most of the functions follow the rule of respecting immutability (in particular `===`). I think `ismutable` for string should either change its docstring or return `false` (my personal opinion is that it should return `false`).

Comment: So in practice Sets are immutable but mutable, and Strings are mutable but immutable ;-)

Comment: I have never needed to use `ismutable` in my code. I think it is best to treat it as a low-level function used when working with internals to get `mutable` field of the type of the variable you have.

Comment: Actually, with your answers to this question and my [other question on structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64909449/does-for-struct-check-recursively-in-julia-it-seems-not), I understand now way better the `==` and `===` operators. Thanks